# Changing border of a radio Button in Cognos

Tags: radio-button, cognos

How do I change or make the border disappear of Radio Buttons in Cognos?
I am trying to give padding between the text in a radio button and the border.
I tried adding a table border but still the radio buttons border persists and looks ugly.

Comment: I have tried 1) Editing Size and Overflow tab 2) adding radio button inside a table and editing border which obviosly is not the solution since the border of the radio button still persist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS:

```
<style>
.clsCheckBoxList {
    border: none;
}
</style>
```

Put this in an HTML Item on your prompt page and all radio buttons will no longer have borders.

---

If you want to target a specific radio button prompt while not affecting others, wrap it with a span and give the span an ID.

Add an HTML item with following contents right before the prompt:

```
<span id="myradiobutton">
```

Add a second HTML item with the following contents right after the prompt:

```
</span>
```

Modify your CSS to use the span's ID to isolate the radio button group desired:

```
<style>
#myradiobutton .clsCheckBoxList {
    border: none;
}
</style>
```